# How to change navigation bar color in chrome custom tab?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Is there any ways to change the navigation bar colour in Chrome Custom Tabs? My app is supporting both light and dark theme but I am getting a white navigation bar when dark theme is applied

Comment: There is no API to set navigation bar color in CustomTabs. It depends on the browser which handles the link. On my Android 8.0 phone Google Chrome has black navigation bar with white icons and Firefox Preview has light navigation with grey icons.

Comment: Looks like navigation color and theme can be controlled since https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/browser#1.2.0-alpha07. You never said which library you were using. It's hard to help if we have to guess everything you did.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please add more information about your problem _ Take a moment to visit SO Help Center section on 'Asking' and specifically the guidelines on producing a Minimal Reproducible example of your code >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in this way.

```
CustomTabColorSchemeParams otherParams = new CustomTabColorSchemeParams.Builder()
         .setToolbarColor(toolbarColor)
         .setNavigationBarColor(navBarColor)
         .build();
 CustomTabIntent intent = new CustomTabIntent.Builder()
         .setColorScheme(COLOR_SCHEME_SYSTEM)
         .setColorSchemeParams(COLOR_SCHEME_DARK, darkParams)
         .setDefaultColorSchemeParams(otherParams)
         .build();
```

For documentation, visit [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.Builder#setColorSchemeParams(int,%20androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabColorSchemeParams)). Check out this [pull request](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/pull/8175) for more details on implementing this.

Comment: @Jack It should have worked. I have used it in one of my pull request. You can see the way to implement it https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/pull/8175.

Comment: My aim is full dark mode theme.

Comment: @Jack No, you cannot achieve full dark mode in chrome custom tabs. They only support dark mode for toolbar, navigation bar and pop-up menu. If you want full dark mode, try to implement webview (but that also support full dark mode in API 29 and above).

Answer (score 0):

```
//custom chrome tab
`implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0"` // Use this dependency only, because setToolbarColor is deprecated in the current dependency.

val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
val intent = builder.build()enter image description here           
builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.YourChoiceColor))
intent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(item.url))
```

[image]